# Prove the following $e^{iAx} = \cos (x)I + i \sin (x) A$

Tags: matrices, exponential-function

the question says as following,

> Let x be a real number and A a matrix such that $A^2 = I$. Show that the $e^{iAx} = \cos (x)I + i \sin (x) A$.

my problem is that I don't know how to deal with this equation using matrix form, I know how to deal with such a question $e^{ix} = \cos (x) + i \sin (x)$ but how to represent the matrix form in a graph in order to get the values of the exponential function $e^{iAx}$.

I will be very happy if someone explains this equation or any reference will be also good.

Thank you

Comment: Use the Taylor development of the exponential function and simplify using the property $A^2=I$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

> $$e^{iAx}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(iAx)^k}{k!}\\=\sum_{k=0,\text{even }k}^\infty\frac{(ix)^k}{k!}A^k+\sum_{k=0,\text{odd }k}^\infty\frac{(ix)^k}{k!}A^k\\=\sum_{k=0,\text{even }k}^\infty\frac{(ix)^k}{k!}I+\sum_{k=0,\text{odd }k}^\infty\frac{(ix)^k}{k!}A.$$

Comment: Thank you so much, I have only a small problem, that is to continue for what you have written, the proof goes as follow $-\cos(x) I + i \sin (x) A$, the minus comes because $i^{n}=-1$ where n is even, now How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you sure that $i^{\text{even}}=-1$ all the time ?

Comment: I think I made a mistake, for n is even, we will have -1 and 1, and for n is odd, we will have -i and i. I just analyse the formula again and it turns out that for the even values $(1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + ...) I + i (1 + \frac{x^3}{3!} + ... ) A $ and this equals $\cos(x) I + i \sin (x) A$, so finally I finished the proof,, Thank you so much for your hint "in fact a solution" ..

Comment: If k starts at 0 in the odd case as well, we get that term twice. Should be k = 1.

Comment: @Owen: odd $k$ starting from $0$ are $1,3,5,\cdots$

Answer (score 1):

Both sides satisfy the same differential equation and have the same initial conditions, so they agree.

More explicitly, let $f(x)=e^{iAx}$ and let $g(x)=I\cos x + i A \sin x$. These are matrix-valued functions of $x$. Compute the following:
$$f'=iAe^{iAx},\quad f''=-e^{iAx},\quad g'=-I\sin x+i A\cos x,\quad g''=-I\cos x -iA\sin x.$$

Therefore $f''=-f$ and $g''=-g$. Moreover $f(0)=g(0)=I$ and $f'(0)=g'(0)=iA$. Thus $f\equiv g$.